# Einstein notation and differential operators.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, differential-operators, index-notation, einstein-notation

So I am dealing with the differential operator $\mathbf{D} = \mathbf{r} \times \boldsymbol{\nabla}$ where $r = x_i \mathbf{e}_i$. We then introduce $(\mathbf{D}f)_i$, which can be expressed as $\epsilon_{ijk}x_j\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_k}$. How would one express $\mathbf{\nabla}\cdot(\mathbf{D}f)_i$ in index notation? I think it includes using the Kronecker delta.

Comment: Isn't it just $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ times the expression you already have? The component index of your expression is $i$ and the repeated index will sum the derivatives w.r.t. $x_i$ of the $i$-th components.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathbf{A}=A_i\mathbf{e}_i$. Since

$$\nabla\cdot\mathbf{A}=\frac{\partial A_i}{\partial x_i}$$, we can write
$$\nabla\cdot\left(\mathbf{D}f\right)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\left(\epsilon_{ijk}x_j\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_k}\right).$$
Using the product rule, we obtain
$$\nabla\cdot\left(\mathbf{D}f\right)=\epsilon_{ijk}\delta_{ji}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_k}+\epsilon_{ijk}x_j\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i\partial x_k},$$
because $\frac{\partial x_j}{\partial x_i}=\delta_{ji}$.

Since $\epsilon_{ijk}\delta_{ji}=\epsilon_{iik}=0$, we arrive at
$$\nabla\cdot\left(\mathbf{D}f\right)=\epsilon_{ijk}x_j\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i\partial x_k}.$$
Note that $\epsilon_{ijk}=-\epsilon_{kji}$ and $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i\partial x_k}=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_k\partial x_i}$. Therefore,
$$\epsilon_{ijk}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i\partial x_k}=-\epsilon_{kji}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_k\partial x_i}=-\epsilon_{ijk}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i\partial x_k}\\
\Longrightarrow\epsilon_{ijk}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i\partial x_k}=0.$$
Finally, we get
$$\boxed{\nabla\cdot\left(\mathbf{D}f\right)=0}.$$